# Rails3.2.x: how to manage background queues on Phusion Passenger?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, delayed-job, passenger

I've got some experience in deploying on Heroku, and I know how to use a [Procfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile) to declare processes.
I generally use either Thin or Unicorn for the web part (http requests handling), and then manage my background tasks using [Delayed Job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job).

Now I'm about to take a Rails 3.2.8 (Ruby 1.9.3) Application running on Heroku and bring it to a "normal" server, where it will run on PhusionPassenger.
I'm not sure about the way Passenger spawns child processes, and how it handles background queues. I need to be sure that web queues don't get filled with time consuming tasks: the ones I used to run in the background on Heroku.

Is there a way to manage Passenger's queues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passenger doesn't handle background queues - typically you'd do exactly as you were doing on heroku and offload those tasks onto delayed job, sidekiq, resque etc.

The only difference would be how you manage those processes. You could keep using a procfile and run them via the foreman gem or you could use something like god or bluepill

Comment: Thanks. I think I'd be more confortable with Foreman and a Procfile. So... how would I set it up? I know how to start Foreman from the command line, but how do I tell Passenger (or Apache) to also start the processes listed in the Procfile?

Comment: You don't - you use foreman directly to start your non web processes

Comment: Ok... so I upload the rails app files to the server, set up the apache config file to let it route traffic to the application... and Passenger starts working.
At the same time I fire Foreman through the command line with `foreman start` as I would do on my computer, and I'll have to do that each time I need to reboot the application or the server.